# From derivatives to gradients in backpropagation

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, neural-networks

Consider the [following explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Matrix_multiplication) of backpropagation from Wikipedia:

> Given an input–output pair {\displaystyle (x,y)}(x,y), the loss is:
>
> $ C(y,f^{L}(W^{L}f^{L-1}(W^{L-1}\cdots f^{1}(W^{1}x)\cdots )))$
>
> The derivative of the loss in terms of the inputs is given by the chain rule; note that each term is a total derivative, evaluated at the value of the network (at each node) on the input $x$:
>
> ${\frac {dC}{da^{L}}}\cdot {\frac {da^{L}}{dz^{L}}}\cdot {\frac {dz^{L}}{da^{L-1}}}\cdot {\frac {da^{L-1}}{dz^{L-1}}}\cdot {\frac {dz^{L-1}}{da^{L-2}}}\cdots {\frac {da^{1}}{dz^{1}}}\cdot {\frac {\partial z^{1}}{\partial x}}$
>
> These terms are: the derivative of the loss function; the derivatives of the activation functions; and the matrices of weights:
>
> $\displaystyle {\frac {dC}{da^{L}}}\cdot (f^{L})'\cdot W^{L}\cdot (f^{L-1})'\cdot W^{L-1}\cdots 
> (f^{1})'\cdot W^{1}.$

So far so good. Then they say:

> The gradient $\nabla$  is the **transpose of the derivative of the output** in terms of the input, so the matrices are **transposed** and the **order** of multiplication **is reversed**, but the entries are the same:
>
> $ \nabla _{x}C=(W^{1})^{T}\cdot (f^{1})'\cdots \cdot (W^{L-1})^{T}\cdot (f^{L-1})'\cdot (W^{L})^{T}\cdot (f^{L})'\cdot \nabla _{a^{L}}C.$

**Why**? i.e. why does converting this to "gradient form" (not sure if that's what they actually did above) requires "transposing matrices and reversing the ordering of multiplication"?

---

In case it helps, I thought this article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) (layout conventions in matrix calculus) may help, but I'm not able to cross-reference hat convention was used above, and why vectors / matrices are transposed, and why they chose to re-arrange the ordering of the terms

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite late, but I also had the same issue while trying to understand back-propagation and implementing it in code. I figure others may run into this as well.

I believe the transpose is there simply to reduce the computational load required to evaluate the first expression, i.e:

$$
{dC \over da^L} \cdot {da^L \over dz^L} \cdots {\partial z^1 \over \partial x}
$$

Since every term after ${dC \over da^L}$ is either a matrix or higher ranked tensor, evaluating it from right to left, as you would, is considerably more expensive than starting with the vector $dC \over da^L$ and having it collapse into more simple vector/matrix operations and then transposing it back at the end; hence, we use the fact that for matrices $A, B, C$ where $ABC$ is defined, $ABC = (C^T B^T A^T)^T$:

$$
ABC = (C^T B^T A^T)^T = (C^T (AB)^T)^T = ABC
$$

And this makes sense because the gradient of a scalar function is, of course, a vector, and for all practical purposes, the transpose of it is insignificant.